# RSS Feed not populating textview

Tags: java, android, textview, rss

I'm trying to build a news reader app for a project that takes the BBC RSS feed and loads it into a textview. All my code seems to be correct but for some reason the textview doesn't populate and I have a sneaking suspicion, after debugging it, that it's caused by the app not implementing open stream. Code is below. Any idea what might be causing the issue?

```
 package com.example.finalproject_newsapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String rss = "";
    boolean item = false;

    private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                                 Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("item"))
                item = true;

            if (!localName.equals("item") && item == true)
                rss = rss + localName + ": ";

        }

        public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                               String qName) throws SAXException {

        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            String cdata = new String(ch, start, length);
            if (item == true)
                rss = rss + (cdata.trim()).replaceAll("\\s+", " ") + "\t";

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView feed = findViewById(R.id.BBC_feed);

        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/us_and_canada/rss.xml");
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
            RSSHandler rssHandler = new RSSHandler();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(rssHandler);
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
        } catch (MalformedURLException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        feed.setText(rss);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "that it's caused by the app not implementing open stream"? You say you debugged your code. Are the callback methods startElement() and characters() called?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't concatenate strings. Use StringBuilder for that.